# Refactoring: Map<String, Double> to Map<String, Double or String>

Tags: java, generics, collections, dictionary

**I've got** widely used method like:

```
public Map<String, Double> parseData(String[] data) {
    .................
```

Where `data` is something like `new String[] { "column1 -> 2.00", "column2 -> New York", ... }`

**Problem:** It appears that `data` can contains both: `String -> Double` & `String -> String` values. So I need smth like:

```
public Map<String, String or Double> parseData(String[] data) {
    ................
```

**Question:** Any ideas besides return `Map<String, Object>`?

Comment: how can 'data' (a String array) hold Double instances???

Comment: @Juvanis like `new String[] { "columnName -> 2.00", "columnName2 -> www.google.com" }`

Comment: another idea is to create a wrapper object to hold the String / Double value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Wrapper `StringOrDouble` which will look a bit like this:

```
public class StringOrDouble {
    private String internalString;
    private Double internalDouble;

    public StringOrDouble(String input) {
        internalString = input;
    }

    public StringOrDouble(Double input) {
        internalDouble = input;
    }

    public boolean hasString() {
        return internalString != null;
    }

    public boolean hasDouble() {
        return internalDouble != null;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return internalString;
    }

    public Double getDouble() {
        return internalDouble;
    }
}
```

Then have a map of type `Map<String, StringOrDouble>` and use that. When you use the values, you can check which one it is by testing with `hasString()` and/or `hasDouble()`. Alternatively you could have an enum which determines which type it is.

Comment: @StanislavL Guess so. ^^

Answer (score 2):

```
public Map<String, Container> parseData(String[] data)
```

You can introduce a wrapper class for this

```
public class Container {
    private String s;
    private Double d;

    public Container(String s) {
         this.s=s;
    }
    public Container(Double d) {
         this.d=d;
    }
    public hasString() {
         return s!=null;
    }
    public hasDouble() {
         return d!=null;
    }
//getters/setters
}
```

Comment: As this is probably for output only, I wouldn't add setters but only getters. Otherwise things could get confusing.

Comment: +1, Container is a more general term. What if `int` or some enumerations come after? In this case you don't have to rename your type...

Comment: @GaborSch it is more general, yes. `StringOrDouble` makes it clear what is contained which can be useful at times. If modifications are probable, a more general term can be a good idea though. It all depends.

Comment: @blalasaadri Actually I'd name it as `ValueContainer` - that would describe its purpose best.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want something like `Map<String, ? extends String || Double` as the return type, but no such thing is supported in Java:

> 4.9 Intersection Types An intersection type takes the form T1 & ... & Tn, n>0, where Ti, 1in, are type expressions. Intersection types arise
>   in the processes of capture conversion (§5.1.10) and type inference
>   (§15.12.2.7). It is not possible to write an intersection type
>   directly as part of a program; no syntax supports this. The values of
>   an intersection type are those objects that are values of all of the
>   types Ti, for 1in.

So you'd better parse the input array and hold different arrays for each different type or you can use a wrapper class to represent the values in the map returned, as some other answerers explained.

Comment: yes sure. That's first that comes in mind. But due app logic I can't split map into two.

Answer (score 0):

Use superclass:

```
public Map<String, Object> parseData(String[] data)
```

Comment: but the idea of generics is to strict containing data type. I need `String` and `Double` only. `Object` doesn't imply any restrictions on input type

Comment: but it keeps code simple. you could also define your own super class.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative to @blalasaadri. don't pretend to be better:

```
 public static class StringDoubleValue {
        private final Optional<String> sValue;
        private final Optional<Double> dValue;

        public MetricValue(String sValue) {
            this.sValue = Optional.of(sValue);
            this.dValue = Optional.absent();
        }

        public MetricValue(Double dValue) {
            this.sValue = Optional.absent();
            this.dValue = Optional.of(dValue);
        }

        public Object get() {
            return (sValue.isPresent()) ? sValue.get() : dValue.get();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            if (sValue.isPresent()) ? sValue.get() : dValue.get().toString();
        }
    }
```